# Java 8 for Minecraft Forge Error (Debian 10)

Tags: java, javascript, minecraft

I tried to install Java 8 in addition to Java 11 on my VPS. Apparently that was only moderately successful. It is displayed under "java -version". And also with "sudo update-alternatives --config java", but the vServer still does not want to start.

https://pastebin.com/jzp4CeGi

Answer (score 0):

You're running a 32-bit JRE ("linux-x86") on a 64-bit kernel:

```
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode linux-x86 )
```

A 64-bit JRE/JDK should resolve the issue, `java -version` should show `64-Bit Server VM` in the output. This seems to be related to [JDK-8023956](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8023956).